# Zsh - Delete current/previous argument entirely

Tags: zsh

I'm using zsh with Macos. Currently, ctrl+w deletes a 'word' but stops at non-word characters. It's kinda odd though because it'll often delete far more than it should or stop at odd places:

Examples:

```
open -n https://www.google.com // deletes [com][google.][www.][https://(why so much?)]
open -n 'https://www.google.com' // deletes [com'][google.][www.][https://][n '(wtf?)][open -]
```

I just want to delete the current string backwards until a space character, effectively deleting an argument. I've looked online at various bash/zsh hotkeys you can add to .bashrc, but none seem to do what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can't reproduce (at least in 5.7.1); ctrl+w deletes back to the `:` in both cases.

Comment: BTW, adding anything to `.bashrc` won't affect `zsh`.

Answer (score 16):

Update: The `select-word-style` function[0] is available as an easy way to customize the word style:

```
$ select-word-style
Usage: select-word-style word-style
where word-style is one of the characters in parentheses:
(b)ash:       Word characters are alphanumerics only
(n)ormal:     Word characters are alphanumerics plus $WORDCHARS
(s)hell:      Words are command arguments using shell syntax
(w)hitespace: Words are whitespace-delimited
(d)efault:    Use default, no special handling (usually same as `n')
(q)uit:       Quit without setting a new style
```

To only stop at argument boundaries,

```
autoload -Uz select-word-style
select-word-style shell
```

should suffice.

[0] https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Functions/Zle/select-word-style

The original answer below assumes the normal style.

---

`^W` is bound to `backward-kill-word` by default in ZLE[1]. What it considers as word is controlled by `WORDCHARS`[2].

> `WORDCHARS <S>`
>
> A list of non-alphanumeric characters considered part of a word by the line editor.

In order to recognize `https://www.google.com` as a word, you at the very least need

```
WORDCHARS+=':/.'
```

Add this to your `~/.zshrc`, and add whatever non-alphanumeric characters you would like to be treated as word chars (all of them if you always want to kill the last argument).

[1] http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html

[2] http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-WORDCHARS

Comment: You probably want `WORDCHARS+=:` to avoid replacing the characters already considered part of a word. `/` and `.` are already part of the value.

Comment: @chepner Sure, edited. Personally I curate this list myself and I'm not actually sure what the default is. (Of course, for framework users, they probably have a framework default value.)

Comment: @chepner - I've added that to my file and reloaded it using "source ~/.zshrc". I don't see any change in behaviour?

Comment: Which keybindings are you using, emacs or vi?

Comment: @chepner - I'm not sure, I guess whatever zsh uses by default?

Comment: What did you add to .zshrc? `WORDCHARS+=':/.'` or `WORDCHARS+=:`? From your question the latter clearly isn't enough.

Comment: Just realized I forgot `select-word-style` when I first wrote the answer. I've updated the answer and it should be simpler and more foolproof now.

Comment: @4ae1e1 Sorry to be a bother, but I'm not really sure how to apply your suggestion. Are steps possible?

Comment: Put the code in ~/.zshrc. Start a new shell. Profit.

Answer (score 9):

I personaly configure **`zsh`** to use **`vim`** style editing, and then, I add some keybindings similar to **`emacs`** style. Examples:

- **`<ctrl+w>`**: delete word backward
- **`<escape><d><T><space>`**: delete back until space (like **`vim`**). This might be what you want.

My **`~/.zshrc`**:

```
## editing mode e=emacs v=vim
export KEYTIMEOUT=1
bindkey -v

## more keys for easier editing
bindkey "^a" beginning-of-line
bindkey "^e" end-of-line
bindkey "^f" history-incremental-search-forward
bindkey "^g" send-break
bindkey "^h" backward-delete-char
bindkey "^n" down-history
bindkey "^p" up-history
bindkey "^r" history-incremental-search-backward
bindkey "^u" redo
bindkey "^w" backward-kill-word
bindkey "^?" backward-delete-char
```

My logic, take the good of both **`vim`** and **`emacs`** styles:

- The style of **`<ctrl+a> <ctrl+e> <ctrl-w> ...`** is so convenient. I've been using it for decades so I keep it. No changes in `WORDCHARS` or something.
- However, when I need some more advance editing, then I use **`vim`** style, which is better.

As for arrows and **`<home> <end> ...`** keys:

```
## create a zkbd compatible hash;
##   to add other keys to this hash, see: man 5 terminfo
typeset -A key

key[Home]=${terminfo[khome]}
key[End]=${terminfo[kend]}
key[Insert]=${terminfo[kich1]}
key[Delete]=${terminfo[kdch1]}
key[Up]=${terminfo[kcuu1]}
key[Down]=${terminfo[kcud1]}
key[Left]=${terminfo[kcub1]}
key[Right]=${terminfo[kcuf1]}
key[PageUp]=${terminfo[kpp]}
key[PageDown]=${terminfo[knp]}

## setup keys accordingly
[[ -n "${key[Home]}"        ]] && bindkey "${key[Home]}"            beginning-of-line
[[ -n "${key[End]}"         ]] && bindkey "${key[End]}"             end-of-line
[[ -n "${key[Insert]}"      ]] && bindkey "${key[Insert]}"          overwrite-mode
[[ -n "${key[Delete]}"      ]] && bindkey "${key[Delete]}"          delete-char
[[ -n "${key[Up]}"          ]] && bindkey "${key[Up]}"              up-line-or-history
[[ -n "${key[Down]}"        ]] && bindkey "${key[Down]}"            down-line-or-history
[[ -n "${key[Left]}"        ]] && bindkey "${key[Left]}"            backward-char
[[ -n "${key[Right]}"       ]] && bindkey "${key[Right]}"           forward-char
[[ -n "${key[PageUp]}"      ]] && bindkey "${key[PageUp]}"          history-beginning-search-backward
[[ -n "${key[PageDown]}"    ]] && bindkey "${key[PageDown]}"        history-beginning-search-forward
[[ -n "${key[Home]}"        ]] && bindkey -M vicmd "${key[Home]}"   beginning-of-line
[[ -n "${key[End]}"         ]] && bindkey -M vicmd "${key[End]}"    end-of-line
[[ -n "${key[Insert]}"      ]] && bindkey -M vicmd "${key[Insert]}" overwrite-mode
[[ -n "${key[Delete]}"      ]] && bindkey -M vicmd "${key[Delete]}" delete-char
```